# return different response without persistent data?

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

I want to mock a server endpoint where when user hit the api the n times, the response will return extra properties value.

for example the endpoint return this at first

```
[{id: 1, price:null}]
```

then at second call return this `[{id: 1, price: 10}]`

I tried this setTimeout attempt, doesn't make sense because the frontend (client) hit the endpoint every seconds and the function will got executed from top to bottom again.

```
const data = [/*...*/];

 let loading;
 function load() {
   for(const el of data)
     el.score = Math.random();
 }

 app.get("/api/", (req, res) => {
   if(!loading) loading = setTimeout(load, 5000);

   res.json({ data });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

the `load` function is called asynchronous but not the response. Put `res.json()` to the callback function of `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  load();
  res.json(data);
}, 5000);
```

NOTE: send `data` not `{data}`

Comment: it doesn't matter? the client side is call the endpoint every seconds..

Answer (score 0):

Is this you wanted? I didn't understand why you had used 'loading' variable.

```
const data = [{ id: 1, price: null }];

let loading;
function load() {
  for (const el of data) el.price = Math.random();
}

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  //   if (!loading) loading = setTimeout(load, 5000);
  //   res.json({ data });

  load();
  res.json(data);
});
```

If load() function takes time, you may need to consider to move that as promise.

Comment: if the client side constantly hit the route how does the data persist?